# switching monitors from the cmdline in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, display

Windows 7 and above has this [useful "displayswitch.exe" tool](http://jeffwouters.nl/index.php/2012/06/switch-your-display-through-the-command-line/) which can be invoked with the Win+P shortcut. I'm trying to replicate this feature in my old Windows XP installation using [Clavier+](https://code.google.com/p/clavier-plus/) and a batch script.

I prefer a solution that does not require installing other 3rd party tools aside from these:
AMD's own CCC, Ray Adams' ATI Tray Tools, and [NirSoft's freeware tools](http://www.nirsoft.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an acceptable solution using [Nirsoft's MultiMonitorTool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html):

```
MultiMonitorTool.exe /switch 1 2
```